# relational algebra, am I correct?

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I doing some relational algebra and kinda hit with this question, I did it, but doubt I have done it correctly.
So these are the 3 relations:

```
Musicians: ssn, name, annualIncome
Instruments: instrID, iname, key
Plays: ssn, instrID
```

The questions is find instrID played by a musician name John.

What I did was:

```
T1 = proj  [condition ssn] ( select [name = John] Musician)
T2 = Plays natural joins Instruments

Result = proj [instruID] (T1 natural joins T2)
```

It seems like I get every John that play the instruments instead of one specific john... how can I pick one john using relational algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying assumption is that there is only one musician called John: otherwise the question does not seem to make sense.

`proj[instrID] (proj[ssn]( select[name = John] Musician) naturalJoin Plays)`

should answer the question. You do not need table `Instruments` since you can get the `instrID` already from `Plays`.